# Excel VBA Multiplying a variable by a value in Conditional Formatting Formula

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have a conditional formatting for a leave tracker color that I was trying to multiply the calculation for H1 and H2 by 0.5 since half days will only be contributing 0.5 of the day to the leaves total, and the calculation is that the total leaves for the team in a day that are less than/ equal to 20% is green, between 20-40% is yellow and greater than 40% of the people on leave is shaded red.

I currently have this formula for one of the color codes (I have 3 color codes, one for red, yellow and green):

```
=AND(((COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"O")+COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"L")+COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"H1")+COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"H2")+COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"OY")+COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"M")+COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"V")+COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"P"))/2)>0.2,((COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"O")+COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"L")+COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"H1")+COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"H2")+COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"OY")+COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"M")+COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"V")+COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"P"))/2)<=0.4)
```

I have tried to multiply the H1 and H2 by 0.5 like this but it didnt work [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEfUo.png)

```
=AND(((COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"O")+COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"L")+ (COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"H1") * 0.5)+ (COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"H2")*0.5 )+COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"OY")+COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"M")+COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"V")+COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"P"))/2)>0.2,((COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"O")+COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"L")+COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"H1")+COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"H2")+COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"OY")+COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"M")+COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"V")+COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"P"))/2)<=0.4)
```

Comment: How can your condition ever be true? Since each separate `COUNTIF` statement is mutually exclusive to the others, `COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"O")+COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"L")+COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"H1")+COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"H2")+COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"OY")+COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"M")+COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"V")+COUNTIF(ME12:ME13,"P")` can only ever evaluate to either **0**, **1** or **2**. So, dividing by 2 as you are, it can only ever be either **0**, **0.5** or **1**. Which means it can **never** simultaneously satisfy the two conditions you are imposing, i.e. >0.2 and <=0.4.

Comment: Try using helper columns to break all the conditions down to simple elements. That is much easier to debug and to maintain in case sth changes in 6 months ...

Comment: @JosWoolley Yes, that is correct. The goal of the formula was to ensure that it only falls under one condition, which corresponds to a color highlight

Comment: @Ike Thanks! I was wondering if you would be able to provie an example of what that would look like?

Comment: As you don't show the header columns in your screenshot it is hard to guess how your formulas should work, where there are situated etc. You need to provide a minimal dataset. See [repro] and use [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)